# Windows 7 recovery doesn't work

Tags: windows-7, laptop, sony-vaio

My laptop has been very slow during the past months. I decided to use windows recovery options to restore it to its original factory condition but it does not work, whichever option I try it restarts but then returns to windows login window and does nothing. I have no recovery disks. What should I do?

Comment: Backup your data. Format the HDD. Reinstall Windows.

Comment: You need to hit a special F key (early during boot) to bring up the recovery boot menu.  I think it's F11 or F12.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: Those F keys doesn't have recovery options!

Comment: There is the standard "bring up BIOS" F key, and a different one that brings up the recovery menu.  At least on my Vaio VGN this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

On most PCs, where you have not changed the HDD and have still got the recovery partition intact, pressing F8 during boot (after BIOS, before Windows) should give you recovery options.

Alternatively, I hear F10 when the Vaio logo is on the screen is the Sony specific option. After you have pressed this, follow the instructions (it's fairly self explanatory) in order to restore your computer.

Please ensure you have backed up any files you want to keep.

Comment: See [How to Recover Factory Settings on Sony Vaio Computer with Windows 7](http://www.ehow.com/how_7680511_recover-vaio-computer-windows-7.html), section "Recover Using Recovery Partition".